# How to return the index for each element in a vector or data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, indexing

When I have attempted to research this question, I find a lot of references to the which() function. I have not been able to adapt that to my present needs. I hope the following will illustrate what I am attempting to do and why:

```
test <- c("c","b","a","e","d")
test <- as.data.frame(test)
colnames(test) <- "code"
# How can I return the index for each item in the vector?
# test$indx <- ?

# Desired outcome
#     code  index
# 1    c     1
# 2    b     2
# 3    a     3
# 4    e     4
# 5    e     5

# hard-coding desired output to illustrate why I want it
test$index <- seq(from = 1, to = 5, by = 1)

library(dplyr)
test <- arrange(test, code)
test
#   code index
# 1    a     3
# 2    b     2
# 3    c     1
# 4    d     5
# 5    e     4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how

```
test <- c("c","b","a","e","d")
test <- as.data.frame(test)
colnames(test) <- "code"
test$index <- 1:nrow(test)
test

library(dplyr)
test <- arrange(test, code)
test
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to get it. Running it as shown and entering "text" seems to indicate that the index numbers are row names; not what I'm looking for. Modifing to "test$indx <- 1:nrow(test$code)"  yields an error "argument of length 0"

Comment: @ChuckBV try running it now, I think it should produce the index column which will produce your desired output? Note in the example above just change it to `test$indx <- 1:nrow(test)`